# R: Produce Index Values to Group Increasing Values in Vector

Tags: r, vector, counter

I have a list of increasing year values that occasionally has breaks in it and I want to create a grouping value for each unbroken sequence.  Think of a vector like this one (missing 2005,2011):

```
x <- c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2013,2014,2015,2016)
```

I would like to produce an equal length vector that numbers every value in a run with the same index to end up with something like this.

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

I would like to do this using best R practices so I am trying to avoid falling back to a for loop but I am not sure how to get from Vector A to Vector B.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Some things I know I can do:

- I can flag the record before or after a gap as true with an ifelse
- I can get the index of when the counter should change by wrapping that in a which statement

This is the code to do each

```
ifelse(!is.na(lag(x)) & x == lag(x)+1, FALSE, TRUE)

which(ifelse(!is.na(lag(x)) & x == lag(x)+1, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Comment: `cummax(c(1, diff(x)))`

Comment: Ohhh, I never thought of using cummax to make a running counter.  That works really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there a couple solutions to this problem.  One as d.b posted in the comment above that will produce a sequence that increments every time there is a break in the sequence.

```
cummax(c(1, diff(x)))
```

There is a similar solution that I chose to use with ifelse() flagging breaks and cumsum().  I chose this solution because additional information,like other vectors, can be included in the decision and diff seems to have problems with very erratic up and down values.

```
cumsum(ifelse(!is.na(lag(x)) & x == lag(x) + 1, FALSE, TRUE))
```